# How do you pronounce "HTTPS"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

When I refer HTTPS, I pronounce it by reading each character. However, I wonder whether there is a quicker and easier way to pronounce it.

Comment: Nope.  Letter by letter is how it’s done.   What were you hoping for?.. Hot piss?  Hot teepees? Hottie Peas?

Comment: Aich tee-tee PS.  What you write down after you pee.

Answer (score 2):

HTTPS is pronounced as you said you pronounce it, by reading each letter.

It's also referred to as HTTP Secure or Secure HTTP. It stands for Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard someone spell it out like that, except perhaps in a lecture.  (And I've been in computers/programming since 1968.)

Comment: OK, I'll give you that. I modified my response. It's often helpful to know what an acronym stands for.